# How can I find a specific data, such as a Date in my Excel file, then write time on the column next to it using VB 6.0?

Tags: excel, vb6

```
Set oExcel = 
CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim fName As String 'full file path and name
 fName = App.Path & "\Data" & "\" & Label4.Caption & "" & "\" & Label4.Caption & ".xls"

Set oBook = oExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open(fName)
'opens the fname workbook

Set oSheet = oExcel.Application.ActiveSheet 'activate the first worksheet
```

I managed to store the current date (label2.caption) and Time In (label1.caption) with this:

```
oSheet.Range("A1").Value = Label2.Caption
oSheet.Range("B1").Value = Label1.Caption
oExcel.Quit
```

but the thing is I want my program to check if there is already a current date and time in saved on my excel file, and store a lunch out time if there is. My next problem is if I will time in tomorrow, how can my program store data on the next row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check if the current cell you are trying to write to has a value or not (`.Value = ""`). If not, then you can go ahead. If there is a value, you need to do some steps:

a- Select the last existing value in the current column(i.e: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>)

b- Go one cell down to reach an empty cell

c- write the value

Here is the code for cell A1. I am sure you can manage to replicate it for column B.

```
If oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
      'Cell A1 is empty
      oSheet.Range("A1").Value = Label2.Caption
Else
      'Cell A1 has a previous value. Let's select the closest empty cell down
      oSheet.Range("A1").Selection.End(oExcel.xlDown).Select

      'Now, we are on the last existing cell
      'lets move one cell down to have an empty cell
      oSheet.ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select

      'Now we can write the value
      oSheet.ActiveCell.Value = Label2.Caption
End If
```